# My electric guitar gets noisy when I bend over

Tags: electric-guitar

I initially thought this was coincidence but in my home setup when I lean forward (with my guitar) to adjust something, I get noise that goes away when I stand back up.

If I had an open microphone I could understand it, but I don't. And I don't have my output volume very loud at all anyway.

What might be causing this - could it be something mechanical in the guitar?

Comment: Does the same phenomenon occur when someone else bends over with your guitar? What about if someone else turns it? What sort of 'noise' is it? It's probably just the guitar being too close to the amp. Does it happen with another amp?

Comment: I'll test next time I play. Why would being close to the amp do this, exactly? Is it feedback similar to having a mic near loudspeakers?

Comment: It could also have to something to do with some electrical interference in your house.. like fluorescent bulbs or some other RF generator. Try it in a different room/house and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: This is called flatulence. <runs and hides>

Answer (score 3):

Could be feedback from speaker to guitar.  There is acoustic feedback where the strings vibrate driven by the speakers, and magnetic feedback where the magnetic field from the speaker feeds directly into the pickups (the latter tends to be a really bad kind of howl/screech though).

The latter happens easier with single-coil pickups than with double since the latter are actually designed to be bad at picking up external magnetic fields.